# UV Unwrap at seams gives unexpected result

Tags: uv

I'm trying to learn UV unwrapping.

I've an object where I marked the seems. When I UV unwrap it, some (planar polygon) faces unwrap in an unexpected way:

[image: screenshot]

It appears blender detects something that is not there.

**What causes the distortion and how do I get rid of it?**

Is this because I use polygons (all polygons are planar) instead of triangles?

**Update**
I posted the .blend file on blendexchange:
[image]

Comment: It seems you didn't add a seam across the length of your model.
This would help you to control the unwrap a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I unwrapped your model again and the other side also gave the same result. Then I tried *Smart UV Project* and all your shapes came out nicely. In conclusion I think you are better off doing the *Smart UV Project* instead of the standard *Unwrap* and as far as why the standard unwrap does this, I think it's because of the way Blender's default unwrap algorithm works.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an extra face there. Try deleting the face and see if it clears up. Ideally you want to make sure you limit your ngons. You can always fill that area (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>), then convert the face to triangles (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), then convert to quads (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>). That's a quick way of getting rid of ngons.

Comment: Is there a method to 'see' the extra face?